# D3 how do you center an element with pan/zoom enabled?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

My current updated solution...

```
var myZoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
              .scaleExtent([.3, 10])
              .on("zoom", zoom);

var container = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .style('border', '1px solid black') 
    .call(myZoom);

var trans1 = 250;
function sneakyTranslate1() {
    if(trans1 <= 0) return 0;
    trans1 = trans1 - .5;
    return trans1;
}
var trans2 = 250;
function sneakyTranslate2() {
    if(trans2 <= 0) return 0;
    trans2 = trans2 - .5;
    return trans2;
}
//I am centering my node here, but if I pan the node it jumps
var svg = container.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(250,250)"); 

 function zoom() { svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + 
    (d3.event.translate[0]+sneakyTranslate1()) + "," + 
    (d3.event.translate[1]+sneakyTranslate2()) + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale +
     ")"); }
```

To clarify I want to initially center my single node then allow panning and zooming to work as default. The user can worry about centering and panning as they add more nodes.

My current solution is to translate my group where my node is. Add that translated offset to the zoom vector in zoom function and slowly decrement the offset value and bring it back to 0.

If anyone know a better way of doing this or reseting the zoom and x,y your nodes before you start drawing it would be helpful.

link [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdc08s06/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your issue now. I updated your jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wdc08s06/7/).

The issue is even though you are translating the SVG `container`, you aren't translating the zoom (kinda weird I know). Essentially the `zoom` function thinks you are trying to zoom in where the SVG container originally was (0,0), but because you moved the container somewhere else (250,250), you have to move the `myZoom` object so it knows where to zoom from.

So if you look I added this

```
//I am centering my node here, but if I pan the node it jump 
var svg = container.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(250,250)");

// translate zoom function so it knows where to zoom from
myZoom.translate([250,250]);
```

So that it knows to translate the zoom object the same place your container is. And I also reverted this back.

```
function zoom() {
  svg.attr("transform",
  "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
  + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Is it possible to retain the pan ability because that is important as the tree grows?

Comment: I have found the solution, it is to  "translate("+ (d3.event.translate[0] +500) + "," + (d3.event.translate[1] +400)  +")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");  If you update your solution, I an accept, but you current solution disabled all panning. Thanks for your help. I have also updated my fiddle with working one.

Comment: I believe I got too excited and jumped the gun. This is only a partial solution. I could make a function that slowly changes the offset back to 0 while the user pans an zoom , but that seem like a hack and not a solution.

Comment: Just clarifying, so you want it so that you can pan but every time you zoom, you zoom towards the node? Is that correct?

Comment: I just want node to be centered at the start with my viewport x and y set to the position of node so it is centered. Then I want panning and zooming to work as default behavior (zoom towards the mouse).

Comment: @BlindOwl I updated my answer. Let me know if that addresses your issue.